Simple circuit to check faulty gates in Proteus

This is my first time using Proteus so bear with me, this is the circuit which I created to test for faulty gates in a quad NAND IC which is a small assignment. First, I want to know if its logic is fine or not and second, when I runs the simulation to test before sending to teacher, it gives me the error that simulation model not found for U2 which is the IC which I imported from Snapeda and when I checked on the pick devices window, it showed no simulation model for it. I tried to add simulation model by following various guides but they all only outputs for a graph and didn't worked for me.
There's also another error which says Simulation failed due to partition analysis error which I think is related to the model file missing.
edit: I was able to fix stuff and understand it a little better and the circuit did worked fully with 7400 NAND gate component in proteus, however I still cant make this SN74ALS00AD IC work because of its simulation model not working.
